# Does AVPlayer stop the user's music?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avplayer

I want to know -- what happens to a user's music when an `AVPlayer` starts to play? Does nothing happen, does it stop, or does the action cancel itself? If so, how would I check and see if the user is playing music?

Apple's Documentation for this confused me.

Comment: Have you tried it for yourself?

Comment: @sangony I didn't get to. I don't have an Apple Developer account. I'm still a senior in high school. I didn't want to spring the $99/year and get a Tax ID until before I had to implement multiplayer and Game Center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, looking up the info for this, it seems that `AVAudioPlayer` objects only interrupts the user's audio if the app's `AVAudioSession`'s category is set to `Solo Ambient`, the default.

I saw this answer: [App with AVPlayer plays mp4 interrupt iPod music after launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016770/app-with-avplayer-plays-mp4-interrupt-ipod-music-after-launched?rq=1)

I also saw this table in the Apple Developer documentation that explains whether or not different categories interrupt the user's music, with examples of different scenarios, including one for a game: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Sound.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH44-SW1

In order to not interrupt the user's music, I need to set this to `Ambient`.