# Enable the background music back after the app plays a video

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have an app that at the beginning plays a video with AVPlayer. The video is muted. The problem is it stops the music that let say iPhone was playing on iTunes and after the video playback is finished the music does not come back automatically. Is there a way to play the video in my app, during the playback of the video the music on iTunes can be muted which is fine with me, but what I want to achieve is to get the iTunes music back playing when the video is finished without the user's interference.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858173/does-avplayer-stop-the-users-music) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it later on, maybe by tomorrow and let you know if one of those answers help me.

Comment: Nothing in those links worked for me :(